# Yet another "The cursor is READ ONLY."?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My question is different from the others of the kind, because I really need a cursor for rebuilding multiple indices. However, I want to utilise the fact that I am already at the cursor and do an update.

Here is the SQL code:

```
USE [MyDB]
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @IndexName NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

BEGIN TRY 
    DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY KEYSET SCROLL_LOCKS FOR
    SELECT TableName,IndexName
    FROM _NonClusteredIndices_ i
    JOIN _Candidates_ c ON i.ObjectId = c.ObjectId
    WHERE State = 1
    ORDER BY TableName,IndexName
    FOR UPDATE OF i.State
    OPEN c
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TableName,@IndexName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql = 'ALTER INDEX [' + @IndexName + '] ON [' + @TableName + '] REBUILD'
        EXEC(@Sql)
        UPDATE _NonClusteredIndices_ SET State = 2 WHERE CURRENT OF c
        FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TableName,@IndexName
    END
    CLOSE c
    DEALLOCATE c
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE() as ErrorState,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() as ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() as ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```

Alas, I get **The cursor is READ ONLY**

Why? How do I fix it?

**EDIT**

The DDL of the two tables is:

```
USE [MyDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_Candidates_](
    [ObjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClientIdColumnId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TableName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ClientIdColumnName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [RowCount] [bigint] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_NonClusteredIndices_](
    [ObjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IndexName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [State] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

(Oops, listed a wrong table)

None of the tables have any indices or constraints, except the default constraint for the `_NonClusteredIndices_.State` column

Comment: Can you provide the DDL for both tables?

Comment: I read that post and it guided me to add `LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY KEYSET SCROLL_LOCKS`, but still no dice. Other than that I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I might be missing something, if you see it - please share.

Comment: Accidentally listed the DDL for a different table. Fixed now,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the tables referenced by the `CURSOR` has no unique index, the `CURSOR` will be converted to `STATIC`. And `STATIC` cursors are `READ-ONLY`. See [Using Implicit Cursor Conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190641(v=sql.100).aspx) for more information.

As an alternative, I suggest you get rid of the `CURSOR` altogether and do this using a set-based query:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        SELECT 
            @sql = @sql + 'ALTER INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(IndexName) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(TableName) + ' REBUILD;' + CHAR(10)
        FROM _NonClusteredIndices_ i
        JOIN _Candidates_ c 
            ON i.ObjectId = c.ObjectId
        WHERE State = 1;

        EXEC(@sql);

        UPDATE i
            SET i.State = 2
        FROM _NonClusteredIndices_ i
        JOIN _Candidates_ c 
            ON i.ObjectId = c.ObjectId
        WHERE State = 1;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
    DECLARE
        @ErrorNumber    INT,
        @ErrorMessage   NVARCHAR(4000),
        @ErrorState     INT,
        @ErrorSeverity  INT,
        @ErrorLine      INT;

    SELECT
        @ErrorNumber    =   ERROR_NUMBER(),
        @ErrorSeverity  =   ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState     =   ERROR_STATE(),
        @ErrorLine      =   ERROR_LINE(),
        @ErrorMessage   =   ERROR_MESSAGE();

    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
END CATCH
```

Comment: I am aware of this approach, but there is a problem with it. It cannot be stopped in the middle and resumed. Some of the indices are very big, the operator may stop the session check something and then resume it. I cannot rebuild all the indices in the same transaction. Plus the real query outputs progress messages using `RAISERROR ... NO WAIT`

Comment: @mark then put a unique index on `_NonClusteredIndices_`.

Comment: i can, easily, but haven't you just said that doing so converts the `CURSOR` to be `STATIC` and thus `READONLY`?

Comment: @mark I'm sorry I misspoke. It should be :`If one of the tables referenced by the CURSOR has no unique index`. See the referenced article.

Comment: Oh, got it. let me try it.

Comment: Added a unique index on each table and it is working now - thanks a lot.

Comment: @mark Glad I could help. Learned a lot from this question!